Porch Step Addition - Dowel and/or height
Good Afternoon,
We are wanting to add a step onto an existing porch that will be 11’ x 13” deep x 6” tall. I’ve already got ~3” of a  base compacted and it would result in me pouring a step that is ~11” tall to get the desired height from where I am now. 2 questions.

Should I continue to build up the base until I only have a 6” height step or leave it as a 11” step with 5” beneath the base?
Should I dowel this to the existing porch? I drilled holes to do that and then seconded guessed with settling and causing damage to the porch if settling did occur.

Thoughts?


Please use a different method to show your picture.  Pretty sure you can even upload here directly.

@Huesmann Got that corrected.

Doweling to the exsting porch will almost always be stronger.  Otherwise, you have very little overturning resistance.

Will I bring in risk of cracking the porch slab if there are any settling/heaving issues on the step?

Yes.  It's a tradeoff.  It behooves you to properly prepare the subbase beneath the new step.
